# why rsyslog is unable to parse incoming syslogs with json template that are forwarded over TCP to some port (say 10514)?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, rsyslog

I am currently forwarding the incoming `syslogs` via `rsyslog`to `local logstash` port. I am currently using the below template that resides in `/etc/rsyslog.d/json-template.conf`

my contents of `json-template.conf` are as under :

```
template(name="json-template"
  type="list") {
    constant(value="{")
      constant(value="\"@timestamp\":\"")     property(name="timereported" dateFormat="rfc3339")
      constant(value="\",\"@version\":\"1")
      constant(value="\",\"message\":\"")     property(name="msg" format="json")
      constant(value="\",\"sysloghost\":\"")  property(name="hostname")
      constant(value="\",\"severity\":\"")    property(name="syslogseverity-text")
      constant(value="\",\"facility\":\"")    property(name="syslogfacility-text")
      constant(value="\",\"programname\":\"") property(name="programname")
      constant(value="\",\"procid\":\"")      property(name="procid")
    constant(value="\"}\n")
}
```

configuration for forwarding in `/etc/rsyslog.conf` :

`*.* @@127.0.0.1:10514;json-template`

`rsyslog` is able to send incoming `syslogs` to port 10514 but it is not able to parse the meaningful information from the `syslogs`.

NOTE: I have same setup for `UDP` and `rsyslog` is able to parse all the msgs as per json template.

I tried the same configuration of rsyslog with UDP :

configuration for forwarding in /etc/rsyslog.conf :

`*.* @127.0.0.1:10514;json-template`

and `rsyslog` is able to parse all the things from the syslog (timestamp, message, sysloghost)

All the necessary configuration for opening of tcp port for tcp forwarding and opening of udp ports for udp forwarding are taken care of as under :

for tcp:
`sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=10514/tcp`

for udp:
`sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=10514/udp`

But only thing I am not able to figure out is what I am missing w.r.t parse syslogs with TCP forwarding.

**Expected outcome: rsyslog should be able to parse syslog as per json template**

Answer (score 1):

I found out the problem. the json-template sends JSON instead of RFC3164 or RFC5424 format.
so we have to add a filter in logstash configuration file to forward the JSON as it is.

My logstash configuration file looks like below :

```
input {
  tcp {
    host => "127.0.0.1"
    port => 10514
    type => "rsyslog"
  }
}
# This is an empty filter block.  You can later add other filters here to further process
# your log lines
filter {
    json {
        source => "message"
    }

  if "_jsonparsefailure" in [tags] {
    drop {}
  }

}
# This output block will send all events of type "rsyslog" to Elasticsearch at the configured
# host and port into daily indices of the pattern, "logstash-YYYY.MM.DD"
output {
  if [type] == "rsyslog" {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
    }

  }
}
```